# ggplot: coordinate axes are unordered when using geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatter plot, but the scale of the axes is messed up. I want it to have an increasing order, but in the plot y = 7 lies between y = 8.8 and y = 11.8.

It is a bit difficult to explain, so I uploaded a picture of the plot to

[image]

```
splot <- ggplot(df, aes(x_val, y_val)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(title) + xlab(label) + ylab(label)

df looks like that

             x_val            y_val            x_min            x_max            y_min            y_max series
1        8.2640626        7.1605616 7.43370308695577 9.09442211304423 5.62731954407747 8.69380365592253   1IWG
2       10.0321728        8.8790822 8.43774194466477 11.6266036553352 6.97682936735609 10.7813350326439   1J4N
3 13.4994332665331 11.8238683366733 12.4200921869666 14.5787743460995 9.99549351881522 13.6522431545315   1KPL
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `str(df)` show. Have you tried `as.numeric()` on the variables? Sounds like they are factors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `str(df)` showed that they are factors `X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "10.0321728","13.4994332665331",..: 3 1 2`. Using `as.numeric()` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str(df)` to examine your data frame `df`. If the variables you are trying to plot are factors, then use `as.numeric()` to convert them so that they are interpreted as numbers. Or you can try to specify that they are numeric when you create your data set, depending on how the frame is defined.